APK Pure deploy app and does not approving
When I pushlish in APK Pure. It display "The version you published is under the publishing review. Please wait…". And after 1 month, I check again and it still display it.
enter image description here
How to fix it, I need help  from everyone, thank you very much

you need help from support of APK pure site, ask them
